# iOS App Deletion: What Remains?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

To my knowledge, when deleting an application, the only remnants of it that can be left behind are Keychain related, right?

I'm not talking about at the hardware level where bits aren't being zeroed out, but at the software level.

If I do a delete/fresh install of an application, the only thing that can physically be left behind by the old application is Keychain stuff, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, you are right, only the keychain remains. If your app supports iCloud key value stores, I would imagine that data would remain on the iCloud servers. But any databases, files, additional plists, values in NSUserDefaults, would all be wiped away.

Comment: Hmm okay.  Trying to debug an issue where I have two users with the same devices, same version of iOS, and same version of my application... One user's app works fine and one, even after delete/reinstall, does not.

Comment: What doesn't work, the delete process? Or just the app in general? I'm in a similar situation, I try to delete as much as I can during the logout process, removing keychain items, user settings, etc. But a hard delete without logout there isn't much you can do.

Comment: I'm actually unsure of what was going on.  But it was boggling my mind that a fresh install after deletion on two devices that, in theory, are exactly the same, works on one and not the other.  My first instinct was to check what gets left behind on an application uninstall.  But it turns out Keychain isn't even the issue, so I'm still working on that...